# Highcharts area chart curves to sharp

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I just started using highcharts and I would like for my chart to display as something like the first image below, instead of the second image.

[image: What I'd like]

What I'd Like

**[image: What I have]**

What I have

Here is the code for what I have currently:

```
chart = new Highcharts.stockChart($('#' + tab + ' .chart')[0], {
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline',
            spacing: [10, 10, 15, 10],
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        interval = setInterval(function() {
                            requestData(asset, name)
                        }, 1000);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },
        },

        rangeSelector: {
                            enabled: !1
                        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: name
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 100,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: "%H:%M:%S",
                minute: "%H:%M",
                hour: "%H:%M",
                day: "%d/%m",
                week: "%Y<br/>%d-%m",
                month: "%m-%Y",
                year: "%Y"
            }
            //tickPixelInterval: 3600
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Values'
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: "#282828"
                },
                y: 12,
                zIndex: 4,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, countDecimals(this.value))
                }
            },
            opposite: false,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                dashStyle: 'longdashdot',
                color: '#2D2E2F'
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Price',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: !1,
                groupPixelWidth: 1
            },
            animation: !1,
            threshold: null,
            //color: '#2D2E2F',
            data: []
        }],
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        layout: 'horizontal'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            align: 'left',
                            x: 0,
                            y: -5
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    });
```

PS: The data from both charts are almost the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `series.dataGrouping: {enabled: false}` instead of `!1`.

Comment: Done that, doesn't work.

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle with representative data.